# Translate Animation on Android across layouts

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a linearlayout that has 3 custom layouts and I want translate a view from the top one to the bottom one.

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
```

So I want to move A to B or to C.  Right now I am just doing A to B, but when I do the animation A ends up under the B layout (like sliding a card under another one).  How can I get A to appear on top of B during the animation?

Here is the animation code:

```
public static Animation makeWinAnimation(View from, View to){
   TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, to.getLeft()-from.getLeft(),
       0, from.getLeft()-to.getTop());
   ta.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
   return ta;
}
```

Comment: How are you doing the animation? Can you please paste the code involved?

Comment: Ok are using a `TranslateAnimation`. That is fine but there are more powerful things out there now. 
Take a look at: `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition();`
I happen to have a repo with examples on Android animations. It might help too: https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations